# Dart Map Key Type Safety

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart

I've implemented enums as keys for my maps, but I'm finding that Dart doesn't provide type safety when retrieving values.

For example, the following code does not cause compilations errors:

```
enum Animal {Bird, Cat, Dog, Horse}

Map<Animal, String> petNames = {
  Animal.Bird: 'Lucky',
  Animal.Cat: 'Cleo',
  Animal.Dog: 'Spot',
  Animal.Horse: 'Sleven',
};

String birdName = petNames[Animal.Bird]; // Positive test
String catName = petNames[1]; // What I want to test
String dogName = petNames['two']; // My control, I expected a compilation error

print(birdName); // Output as expected: Lucky
print(catName); // Output is null
print(dogName); // Output is null
```

Is this a defect in Dart?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, its not a bug. [Here](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Map/operator_get.html) you can check what are you calling when you execute something like `petNames[1]` or `petNames['two']`. Internally, Dart takes the value inside square brackets as an `Object` because you are using the `[]` operator.

When you check the [Map definition](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.7.1/dart-core/Map-class.html), you can see that is defined as a Generic Type (with parameters `K` and `V`). For example when you assign some value to some key on that map:

```dart
petNames[Animal.Bird] = 'New Bird Name'
```

You are using the operator `[]=` and that operator call a function `isValidKey()` to check if the key (`Animal.Bird` in the example) is of type `K` (`Animal`) and the value (`'New Bird Name'` in the example) is of type `V` (`String`).

But `isValidKey()` function is not called when you use the `[]` operator.

So, as in Dart all is an Object, and the `[]` operator get as input an `Object`, when you call `petNames['two']`, Dart will try to find that key, even if it is not of type `K`.

For more information please check the links above and this [issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/26491) on Dart Lang SDK.

Comment: Great answer!  I was trying to track down an issue that covered this with no luck; thank you for sharing!